# How to replace substring in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

To replace substring.But not working for me...

```
var str='------check';

str.replace('-','');
```

**Output:** -----check

Jquery removes first '-' from my text. I need to remove all hypens from my text. My expected output is 'check'

Comment: Incidentally, this is plain Javascript, not jquery.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp Here it is...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

simplest:

```
str = str.replace(/-/g, "");
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this instead:

```
str = str.replace(/-/g, '');
```

`.replace()` does not modify the original string, but returns the modified version.
With the `g` at the end of `/-/g` all occurences are replaced.

Comment: jAndy, your regular expression is inside a string literal, you need to do away with the `'` for this to work :-)  (Also, it's not necessary to escape the hyphen, which has no special meaning outside of a character class).

Answer (score 3):

```
str.replace(/\-/g, '');
```

The regex g flag is global.

Answer (score 3):

`replace` only replace the first occurrence of the substring.

Use `replaceAll` to replace all the occurrence.

```
var str='------check';

str.replaceAll('-','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a short function that loops through and replaces all occurrences, or you can use a regex.

```
var str='------check';

document.write(str.replace(/-+/g, ''));
```